# Bash howto trap errors from inside function

Tags: bash, bash-trap

This is working:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -o errexit

trap 'echo Error on line $LINENO' ERR
echo "start"
false
```

Output is:

```
start
Error on line 6
```

When same code is executed in a function, the trap is not executed:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -o errexit

trap 'echo Error on line $LINENO' ERR

function willFail() {
    false
}

echo "start"
willFail
echo "end"
```

Output is:

```
start
```

How to make a trap executed when something fails inside a function?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/257587/error-propagation-not-working-in-bash

Comment: Setting `set -o errtrace` works. Thanks!